# Sync rendered mouse (WebGL) and Pointer Lock coordinates in WebVR-mode

Tags: webgl, pointerlock, webvr

I am trying to sync my rendered mouse with [pointer lock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API) coordinates. The pointer lock hides the mouse cursor, so that's why I need to draw it separately. I have a 3D-scene with a primitive as mouse pointer. I used [billboarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127061/webgl-draw-polygon-on-near-clipping-plane) to draw the mouse cursor at (0,0, -1), so it looks like a 2D-Object in this 3D-space, nice.

[Lookie lookie](https://i.imgur.com/cBf0Cti.png)

So far so good. For calculating the pointer lock-based x and y coordinate I use this:

```
var movementX = e.movementX || e.mozMovementX || e.webkitMovementX || 0;
var movementY = e.movementY || e.mozMovementY || e.webkitMovementY || 0;
x += movementX;
y += movementY;
```

The first problem is, that I don't know how I initially have to set the x and y coordinates. When you enter the VR-mode the cursor is set to (0,0, -1), so they have to be synchronized in 2D-space. I thought it's something like width/2 or width/4 because of the two eyes, but that didn't work. In addition I need a correct acceleration factor for the rendering, because the mouse is way too fast. Again something with width I guess.

Comment: "I thought it´s something like width/2 or width/4 because of the two eyes, but that didn´t work." -- How exactly did that break? What do you want it to do?

Comment: I need the initial rendered mouse position (0,0,-1) synchronized with 2D coordinate for object picking. I draw the mouse pointer based on the distance of x and y. But the picking isn´t working, because of an offset between pointer lock coordinates and rendered mouse. I thought it might be width/2 or width/4, because it´s the center of the 2D screen.  (0,0,-1) is in (my context) the center of the 3D space.

Comment: mouse events return x and y values in pixel units. If you apply those directly to the position of your rendered cursor, they'll probably move the cursor way off screen immediately (I'm guessing, I don't know what your viewport dimensions are). You probably just need to scale the pixel units down by some factor. `x += movementX / 100` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse events return x and y values in pixel units. If you apply those directly to the position of your rendered cursor, they'll probably move the cursor way off screen immediately. You probably just need to scale the pixel units down by some factor, like `x += movementX / 100` or something.

Comment: Ok that should have been more obvious to me :-/, thanks. However object picking doesn´t work as supposed. Could be the calculations.